# Python importing errors and correct importing guidance

Tags: python, import

My structure is like so

```
/App
__init__.py
    -/dirA
        -__init__.py
        -a.py
    -/dirB
        -__init__.py
        -b.py
/samy_app
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
manage.py
```

Inside of b.py I want to import a.py

So inside of b.py I have

```
from App.dirA import a
```

However the error I'm receiving is "ImportError: No module named 'App'"

I've also tried relative importing with .. but thats not working either.

I would also like to know if I shouldn't put the files in seperate directories like that. It was really for organization. Or should I move them out of the app and place the folders in the same directory as manage.py?

Would really love some help with this. Been trying all day.

sys.path output

```
['', '/root/django-dev', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Thank you everyone for all of the help. Is there maybe something I didnt do when I set up my server? I read the docs and it seems like this import should work without appending any paths...

Comment: Can you please edit to use indents to show the hierarchy of the files?  I.e., are a and b on the same level?

Comment: @Brad I edited the post

Comment: I get a no module named dirA. Am I missing something in my scripts?

Comment: I also edited my post

Answer (score 0):

I believe when I've done this, I usually had to do it like this:

```
from dirA.a import THING_IM_IMPORTING_FROM_A
```

where the root of my application would be the `App` directory.

Comment: His current import should work as well though, see docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).  You should be able to use `from ..dirA import a`.  The absolute import statement should also work.  And `App` does not need to be in the pythonpath because the import also looks in the directory containing the script.

Answer (score 0):

You are mentioning `manage.py`, are you using django perhaps ?

Anyway if you are running a script from dirB you will get an error but if you have structure like this:

```
main.py   
App/
    __init__.py
    dirA/
        __init__.py
        a.py
    dirB
        __init__.py
        b.py
```

and in main.py you have 
`from App.dirB import b`

and in `b.py` you have

`from App.dirA import a` or `from ..dirA import a`

you should be ok.

In any other case you should probably add ../ ( or absolute path of it ) to your `PYTHONPATH`

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
```

but I think it's not a very good idea.

Comment: Adding `../` to your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Yes I'm using django

Comment: Than you should have no problem when you are running from the top using `manage.py` and you shouldn't have main scripts in any of the directories. If you need to run a specific commands use writing custom django manage.py commands like this 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/
Anyway this depends on specifics on your project and needs but you should rethink your directory structure, I guess. All depends on what's in dirA and dirB and which file are you trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misunderstood the question!

Can you verify /App is a nested directory of a directory on your module search path?

In an interactive session, import sys, and type sys.path. The first entry is the CWD or the directory of the top-level program file. If you don't see a directory there leading up to /App, you'll need to add it, as Python searches this list left-to-right when you're importing a package to find the directory that is its parent. You can either edit the PYTHONPATH environment variable, or create a .pth text file and simply type in the directory leading up to it (i.e., /home/user/Documents/code') and put that in your installation directory for Python, or your site-packages folder.

Once that's done, when you check sys.path you'll see, for example, '/home/user/Documents/code'. And /Apps should be within the code folder in this example.

Comment: well the first entry is ' '. is that a problem? haha the second is /root/django-dev

Comment: Which approach is the correct one? edit the PYTHONPATH env variable or creating a .pth text file

Comment: No, '' just means the directory your interactive session is opened in. You'll always see the empty string as the first entry. In fact, if you navigate to the parent directory of /App and open an interactive session, and do your import from there, it should work, too, because your current directory will be the parent of /App.

Comment: Both do the same thing, they're both correct! The PYTHONPATH edit is more common, but I actually like making a simple text file that ends in .pth that I can edit at any time and add multiple lines to for as many different parent directories as I want to add.

Comment: I don't think he should need to edit the pythonpath here.  Read section 6.1.2 directly from the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).  Imports search not only the pythonpath but also the directory containing the input script.

Comment: You're right, the empty string will either be the CWD for the interactive session or the directory of the top-level program file. But looking at his directory structure it doesn't seem like his actual main script is in a directory that is parent to /App? Or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: So I was in the wrong directory when I did the interactive session. I posted my full sys.path

Comment: actually, I dont think I have a main script... do I need to create one?

Answer (score 0):

Parent of the `App` directory should be in `PYTHONPATH` (or `sys.path`). If `App` directory resides in `/home/dorian/mega_project`, then `PYTHONPATH` should contain `/home/dorian/mega_project`.